# ¿Como hago para comparar la hora actual con la hora de entrada y salida?

Tags: java

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        LocalTime horaEntrada = LocalTime.parse("10:00");
        LocalTime horaSalida = LocalTime.parse("14:30");
        LocalTime horaActual = LocalTime.now();
    
        if(horaActual.isAfter(horaEntrada)){
            System.out.println("Hora correcta");
        }else{
            System.out.println("hora incorrecta");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el problema es?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comparar haciendo uso de los metodos propios de la clase `LocalTime` : [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore(java.time.LocalTime)), [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter(java.time.LocalTime)), [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), and [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#compareTo(java.time.LocalTime)).
Si queres comparar `horaEntrada` u `horaSalida` con `horaActual` usando `equals`,debes tener en cuenta lo que te devuelve `LocalTime.now()`

```
 LocalTime horaEntrada = LocalTime.parse("10:00");//Formato devuelto HH:mm
 LocalTime horaSalida =  LocalTime.parse("14:30");

 LocalTime horaActual = LocalTime.now();//Formato devuelto HH:mm:ss..
 
 boolean compa =horaEntrada.equals( horaActual ) ;//aun si la hora actual fuese las 10:00 devolvera false
```

para obtener `LocalTime.now()` con formato HH:mm ,puedes hacer uso de [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-)

```
 LocalTime horaActual=LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")));
 boolean compa =horaEntrada.equals( horaActual ) ;//si la hora actual fuese las 10:00 devolvera true
```

Comment: Si pero si fuera a la 14:29 PM que tire true pero si sale del rango 14:31 que tire un false?

Comment: usando isBefore() e ifAfter() se puede hacer eso